# How can I check the Websocket data is empty by using asyncio

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am use python asyncio to create a websocket client, however, when I try the following code, it hangs up

```
message = b''
while True:
    print(11111)
    chunk = await reader.read(1024)
    print(len(chunk))
    self.message += chunk
    print(self.connection['reader'].at_eof())
    if not chunk:
        break
print('eeeeeeee')
```

However, it hangs up and output:

11111

35

False

How can I check if the buffer is end?

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets are much more complex protocol than plain TCP socket.
You need to use a library for working with it: [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org), [websockets](http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/python/).

P.S.

I'm aiohttp author, the library supports plain HTTP protocol as well as WebSockets.